# Examples of convergence almost surely

Tags: probability, statistics

I know the definition of almost sure convergence, but I don't understand it in practice....for example, if I have independent random variables $$X_n \sim U (1, 1+ 1/n),$$ does it converge almost surely?

Thanks to all!

Comment: No, only the corresponding distributions converge. Not necessarily the random variables.

Comment: @drhab, but $\forall$ sample points $ \omega,\ 1\le X_n(\omega)\le 1+1/n $, right? Doesn't that make $X_n(\omega)\to 1$ as $n\to \infty$?

Comment: Sorry, I misread $X_n\sim U(0,1+\frac1{n})$. Yes you are right, but the extra under condition that the $X_n$ are all defined on the same probability space.

Comment: Yes, I assumed that condition. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 3):

We usually use some auxilliary results to prove almost sure convergence. 
[The Borel–Cantelli lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma) is a very useful result that can be used to prove that a sequence of random variables converges almost surely. If we prove that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\Pr\{|X_n-1|>\varepsilon\}<\infty
$$
for each $\varepsilon>0$, then we have that the events $\{|X_n-1|>\varepsilon\}$ happen only a finite number of times almost surely (we use the Borel-Cantelli lemma here). This means that the sequence $\{X_n:n\ge1\}$ converges to $1$ almost surely.

Since $X_n\sim U(1,1+1/n)$, we have that
$$
\Pr\{|X_n-1|>\varepsilon\}=\Pr\{X_n-1>\varepsilon\}=\Pr\{X_n>1+\varepsilon\}=\Pr\{X_n\in(1+\varepsilon,1+1/n)\}.
$$
If we take sufficiently large $n$, the last probability above is $0$ and the series converges since only a finite number of terms are not equal to zero. Hence, $X_n$ converges to $1$ almost surely.